# Jquery Templates and less then sign (<) or greater then sign (>)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-templates

I am trying to spit out

```
<div><b>From:</b> ${$data.From} <${$data.FromEmail}></div>
```

but the < and > sign is erroring.  The below one works with an extra space.  Anything I should do ?

```
<div><b>From:</b> ${$data.From} < ${$data.FromEmail} ></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encode them as `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

```
<div><b>From:</b> ${$data.From} &lt;${$data.FromEmail}&gt;</div>
```